# Prove perfect elimination ordering graph is perfect

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph with perfect elimination ordering $(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$.

I am trying to prove that $G$ is necessarily perfect graph.

Let $H$ be a subgraph of $G$. Obviously, $H$ has a perfect elimination ordering of its own, lets say $(u_1, u_2, ..., u_m)$. We want to prove that $\chi(H) = \omega(H)$.

> The maximal clique in a PEO graph induced by one of the nodes in the PEO.

Proof: Let $C$ be the maximal clique in $H$. let $u_i$ be the first node of the PEO that appears in $C$. then $C_i$, which is the subgraph induced by $u_i$ and its neighboors, is exactly $C$, as we wanted to prove.

Thus, $\chi(H) = \deg(u_i)$.
Now we need to show that the chromatic number of $H$ is the degree of $u_i$ as well.
$u_i$ and its neighboors form a clique in $H$, thus we need to paint each one of its neighboors in different color. We use exactly $deg(u_i)$ colors. we need to show that we can paint the rest of the graph $H$ using the colors we already used, and here I am stuck unfortunately.

Would like to get some hints on how to move forward from here, or correct me if I have any mistakes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we can finish your reasoning as well, but
we can reason like this.

It is sufficient to prove that $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$.

Let $k=\omega(G)$. It is clear that $\chi(G)\geq k$. Let us prove that $\chi(G)\leq k$.

For this purpose it is enough to prove that there exists a proper colouring of $G$ in $k$ colours.

We will colour our graph $G$ moving from $u_n$ to the beginning of the sequence $u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_n$. Let us colour the vertex $u_n$ with an arbitrary colour.

Let the vertices $u_{i+1},\ldots,u_n$ be already properly coloured in at most $k$ colours. Let us colour $u_i$. The set of neighbours of $u_i$ lying in $\{u_{i+1},\ldots,u_n\}$ together with $u_i$ forms a complete subgraph $W$. By our assumption $|W|\leq\omega(G)=k$. Hence, there are at most $k-1$ vertices among the coloured neighbours of $u_i$. So we can colour $u_i$ so that the colouring is properly.